# CodeIgniter without database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a simple website with CodeIgniter. The site does not need any database at all.

In my *config.php* I have `$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;`

the database is not loaded in *autoload.php*: `$autoload['libraries'] = array();`

I have a simple model that takes care of session and cookie variables. I still get an error message saying the database cannot be loaded! Why, am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: That's weird. By default CI doesn't even use a Database connection. Try a clean ZIP from the site and see if it works.

Comment: I'm already working on a clean copy. I tried it again and I still get the same error.

Comment: My guess is you have the database class invoked somewhere in the code. Search for phrase like "load->database". `sess_use_database` is only responsible for storing session data in the db.

Comment: I do not load database anywhere. I solved the problem by adding "return TRUE" to initialize() method in "system/database/DB_driver.php".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think its maybe here

```
config/database.php
```

around line 63

```
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
```

so **try changing that to FALSE**. comment on db config page says:

```
['autoinit'] Whether or not to automatically initialize the database.
```

Comment: Pretty awkward that autoinit will still bypass the library selection. Never noticed this before. Probably because I never really started a CodeIgniter project without a database :)

Comment: yeah i had to dig to find that, it wasn't something that i knew - the other side is that if it was FALSE by default there would be a million people asking why the database won't load :-)